# Passing data from blade to controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I want to pass a object from the blade file to the controller file. The purpose is when the user click an edit button the user will get a form which is filled with the previous input data. I am using this code in the blade file:

```
<a href="/feestype/{{ $feesType->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

But When I want to get the passed object from the controller's edit method I get a null. My Controller code is like this now:

```
public function edit(FeesType $feesType)
{
    //
    dump($feesType->name);
    return view('feestype.edit',['feesType'=>$feesType]);
}
```

Here I have dump the $feesType object but I get a null. Please help me how can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Comment: Route::resource('feestype','FeesTypesController');

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem. When I dump it is null.

Answer (score 1):

Route model binding works a bit different here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding)

What you need to do is have your route like this:

```
Route::get('feestype/{feesType}/edit', 'YourController@edit')->name('feestype.edit');
```

then in your view

```
<a href="{{ route('feestype.edit', $feesType) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

-- EDIT

using a resource file:

```
Route::resource('feestype', 'YourController')
```

the link will be built the same as above:

```
{{ route('feestype.edit', $feesType) }}
```

Comment: I have used a resource route

Comment: use `php artisan route:list` it will show you the route name that you are using. And then use that within the `route` helper function that I am using above it will be the same

Comment: after using your code I get a new error when dumping: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: you get that in the controller?

Comment: yes. now my controller code is
'public function edit(FeesType $feesType)
    {
        //
        $feesType = FeesType::find($feesType->id);
        dump($feesType->name);
        return view('feestype.edit',['feesType'=>$feesType]);
    }'

Comment: Try as a first line in your controller `dd($feesType);` and check if the model is bound as it should or something else is missing. And make sure that the URL in the view is generated properly but that you also have a feestype with that ID in your database.

Comment: The model works correctly. I have performed a create route bofore with this model. Again the link shows correctly and I have data in database with that id

Comment: so on which line are you getting that error at? I don't have your code to debug.

Comment: now it shows a different error. it says that the property of the Feestype object doesn't exists

Comment: Sorry brother but I cannot help you unless you show a real code. The route model binding should work exactly as documented, and with the example that I gave you because that's how I use it, and I have no problems with it.

Comment: please see in my answer section

Comment: You should edit your question, not give an answer with the problem in your question so other people can answer if they've experienced your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should change your Route to :

```
Route::put('feestype/{id}/edit', 'YourController@edit');
```

For update and edit you should use put not get.

Note that for this code:

```
<a href="/feestype/{{ $feesType->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

first you should compact $feestype in YourController then use your code in blade.

Answer (score 0):

Now the code in the blade file is

```
<a href="{{ route('feestype.edit',$feesType) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

The controller file contains this code:

```
public function edit(FeesType $feesType)
{
    //
    $feesType = FeesType::find($feesType->id);
    dump($feesType->name);
    return view('feestype.edit',['feesType'=>$feesType]);
}
```

And here is my Route definition:

```
Route::resource('feestype','FeesTypesController');
```

And the browser shows this message:
[image]

Comment: And what is your error message? 
btw, you don't have to do this again
`$feesType = FeesType::find($feesType->id);` 
that's why model binding is for, so the `$feesType` parameter should already be full.

Comment: after removing that line it doesn't show that error message now but the object contains null again

Comment: try using `dd` instead of `dump` because I don't know if the problem is in the controller method or somewhere in the view that you are showing.

Comment: And please follow the documentation link that I've shared in my answer to resolve your issue, because it is really hard to find the problem like this. We will spend a whole day.

Comment: the output of dd is added in my next answer

Comment: so the problem is not the controller, it is somewhere in the view. And please keep debugging or raise another Question, not an Answer with your problem. My answer is good for your first problem that you had.

Comment: in which view I have problem?

Comment: if I had problem in view then how my url is corrent after clicking edit button?

Comment: Please do **not** use the answer space for providing additional info or asking follow-up questions; answer space is reserved exclusively for complete and stand-alone answers to the question.